# replace string with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

There is piece of code that replaces the C/o,d/o,s/o or w/o as below :

```
if (temp.contains(",,"))
    {
        temp=temp.replace ("C/O,,","");
        temp=temp.replace ("S/O,,","");
        temp=temp.replace ("D/O,,","");
        temp=temp.replace ("W/O,,","");
    }
```

But i want to replace above by regex so that it automatically removes C or S or D or W  if there is a char sequence ",," I am not able to get what regex can be used .
Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex for C/O in address line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19505835/regex-for-c-o-in-address-line)

Answer (score 2):

You mean this?

```
temp=temp.replaceAll("[SDWC]/O,,","");
```

For case-insensitive match,

```
temp=temp.replaceAll("(?i)[SDWC]/O,,","");
```